# Modal scrolls fails to work if i have modal inside a modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal within a modal and it works properly. but then i notice when the 1st modal exceed from the screen and appears a scroll for the 1st modal it works but when i open the second modal and close it, the 1st modal won't scroll.

Heres a snippet to show you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test1">Open Modal 1 </button>



<div id="test1" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="z-index: 1400;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>

       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal"      data-target="#test2">Open Modal 2</button>
       
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="test2" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="z-index: 1600;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      
      <div class="modal-body">
       
        content
       
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  

</body>
</html>
```

does anyone know why it fails to scroll when i open and close the 2nd modal.?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set overflow: auto; to your #test1 container. this will be the solutiuon

```css
#test1 {
overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test1">Open Modal 1 </button>



<div id="test1" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="z-index: 1400;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>
        sample<br>

       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal"      data-target="#test2">Open Modal 2</button>
       
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="test2" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="z-index: 1600;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      
      <div class="modal-body">
       
        content
       
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks men. it worked. though at first the 1st modal didn't scroll instead it scrolled outside the modal but i tried adding overflow: auto; to the 1st modal . then it scrolled..

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

> "Multiple open modals not supported
>   Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code."

So you'd need to custom code to consider the scroll position and height of each modal.